# Ngnix proxy_pass dosen't work when url contains path

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

im trying to mock sites from my own FS. i want to intercept any http request and redirect it to my server that will return the needed file.
i have wrote a simple default sever:

```
server {
    listen  <<SERVICE_PORT>> default_server;
    server_name _;
    location  / {

        proxy_set_header X-ORIGINAL-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-ORIGINAL-REFERRER $http_referer;
        proxy_set_header X-ORIGINAL-HOST $http_host;
        proxy_pass  <<BROWSE_RESOURCE_URL>>/browsing/resource/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

when a url as "http://exapmle.com" enters it works fine. but when any path is added as "http://exapmle.com/bar" it dose not pass the to <<BROWSE_RESOURCE_URL>>/browsing/resource/. currently i recive 404 but not from my server.

offcurce  i dont need the orignal uri to be concated to my proxy_pass at all.

why dosent it work for me?

Answer (score 1):

From [Nginx's documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> A request URI is passed to the server as follows:
>
> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive

So, for your given configuration, when you request `http://example.com/bar`:

- The normalized request URI will be `/bar`
- The URI specified in the *proxy_pass* directive will be `/browsing/resource/`
- The final URI that will be passed to the backend server is `/browsing/resource/bar`.

You have not configured the backend server to understand `/browsing/resource/bar`. So it only understands `/browsing/resource/`. That's why your backend server returned a 404 not found.

Because you don't want Nginx to combine the request URI with the URI specified in the *proxy_pass* directive, you can use another feature of the *proxy_pass* directive as mentioned in the [Nginx's documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the rewrite directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a request (break):
>
> ...
>
> In this case, the URI specified in the directive is ignored and the full **changed** request URI is passed to the server.

So you will instruct Nginx to rewrite all request URIs to the same URI `/browsing/resource/` as follows:

```
location  / {

    proxy_set_header X-ORIGINAL-URI $request_uri;
    proxy_set_header X-ORIGINAL-REFERRER $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header X-ORIGINAL-HOST $http_host;

    rewrite     ^ /browsing/resource/ break;
    proxy_pass  <<BROWSE_RESOURCE_URL>>;

    proxy_redirect off;
}
```